# is there any way to generate a URL for my operation from Swagger file?

Tags: rest, swagger, ibm-integration-bus

after creating a Rest API in IBM Integration Bus I have a URL like :
 http://:/restapi/v1

and I must add my resource name and parameters after that like :
 http://:/restapi/v1/MyResourceName?param1=value&param2=value
is there any way to generate a URL automatically for my resource from Parameters that I define in REST API Description or Swagger file?

Comment: The operation name does not appear in the URL. What you have called 'myOperationName' is actually the _resource_ name. An 'operation' is a combination of a resource and a verb.

Comment: Thx @kimbert, You are right , I edited it.